# Mantaflow fluid simulation - Why aren't spray and foam controlled by different elements?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm not sure there is an answer to this, but it is very frustrating.

In Mantaflow, I have tried adjusting practically every single parameter in the Spray - Foam - Bubbles section in an attempt to get a reasonable amount of foam with less spray.

Nothing seems to work. Anything that reduces spray also reduces foam.

I guess I'm not understanding what "spray" is in Mantaflow. I assumed it was the particles (droplets) of "water" that break from the main mass of the fluid.

But in my simulation, the water is not falling from a great height, yet I am getting hundreds of thousands of spray particles; roughly three times the amount of foam particles.

The result is a simulation that looks much more violent than it should, with a massive amount of spray particles.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of spray without affecting the amount of foam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tweak how many particles of each type are displayed after the fact. Under the particles tab Viewport Display Amount. And yes it does also change it in render not only viewport.This way you can reduce each particle type individually. For this to work you need to set combined export to none:

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/particles.html) You can find the official documentation where everything is described. Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So you are saying that in that area, if I change the Amount percentage, it will reduce the amount of particles in the render?

Comment: Outstanding! Just tested it, and sure enough it worked! Thank you very much! This was the solution I was looking for!